# PostgreSQL Size Quota on Table or Schema

Tags: postgresql, disk-space, limits

How do one *limit* the size of a PostgreSQL table? (or schema)

Limit in either bytes or rows would be OK.

I'm starting to think that there's no easy and obvious solution.

I have a lot of identical tables in multiple schemas (my take on multi-tenancy) and I would like to restrict each schema to a certain max size.

I have yet to find anything in Postgres that allows me to turn on any kind of quota. So I suppose you need to build this functionality yourself.

The naive 'solution' would be to do something like:

```
insert only if select count(*) < max quota.
```

But that does not feel right.

Anyone with better solutions in mind?

Comment: you'll need to roll your own solution: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BAY149-w576121FBC100CCF74D469CAE5C0@phx.gbl

Answer (score 2):

You can create a trigger that checks the number of records in your destination table when an INSERT is used.

The trigger function would look like this:

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_number_of_row()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$body$
BEGIN
    -- replace 100 by the number of rows you want
    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM your_table) > 100
    THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'INSERT statement exceeding maximum number of rows for this table' 
    END IF;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

And trigger will be like this : -

`CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_number_of_row 
BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_number_of_row();`

**There is no other way i think to set table size in postgresql but u can restrict row limit on table**